# Аналоги Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Алоха! Есть ли аналог Doxygen, скажем так, более общего назначения, чтобы, например, структурировать просто свои заметки текстовые. Раскидываешь куда надо специальные метки, а система потом их собирает в одно представление по указанному шаблону, с поиском и т.д. соответственно. С подобной же гибкой настройкой.

Гугление выдаёт в аналогах что-то вроде Sphinx doc или MkDocs. Но как я понял, это скорее системы генерации статичных страничек html. Почитал немного на их сайтах, но не увидел, чтобы можно было в них как в doxygen закинуть папку, где лежат файлы кода, содержащие особые комментарии, которые doxygen цепляет и структурирует всё в оформленную документацию.

P.S. Doxygen, на сколько я понял, очень жёстко связан с самим ЯП. И берёт тонну информации из структуры кода. Вряд ли он будет адекватно работать с некодом. Хотя вроде, слышал, в нём есть убер гибкая система, которая позволяет сделать практически всё.

Comment: One note наверное подойдет

Comment: @user7860670 да, пользуюсь. Это другое: сначала создай notebook, затем - вкладки, после - страницы. Интересна процедура наоборот. Есть файлы. Расставил в них метки, чтобы система собрала из них тебе Onenote. Подобное делаю через регулярки. По текстам раскиданы условные тэги и категории. И regexp'ом в dnGrep вывожу их. Наткнулся на doxygen, который делает по сути то же самое, но сильно более развит. Но он заточен для работы исключительно с кодом. Есть LaTeX, вроде и с ним знаком. Но не помню, чтобы в нём был регулируемый шаблон вывода в html с плюшками. Плюс всё-таки заточка под книгоиздание.